# Get Index Of Element Within UL

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'd like to be able to get the index of the li where the contained anchor tag's HREF equals "#All". (In this case the correct result would be 3)

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#CPU"><span>CPU</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Pickup"><span>Pickup</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Breakfix"><span>Breakfix</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#All"><span>All</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$("#tabs ul").index($("li a[href='#All']"))
```

...with no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var index = $("#tabs ul li").index($("li:has(a[href='#All'])"));
```

- You were selecting all `<ul>` instead of all `<li>`s you wanted to get the index out of.
- You have to check if the `<li>` element *:has* a link with what you want by using the `:has` selector, otherwise the matched element will be the `<a>` itself instead of the `<li>`.

[Tested the above](http://jsbin.com/axixe) and it gives me the correct answer, 3, as the index is 0-based.

Comment: What if you want to find the index of an a element that has the specified text?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your first rule is matching all UL elements, when you want it to match all LI elements.  Try:

```
$("#tabs ul li").index($("li a[href='#All']"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get an element's index inside another context, as part of a set of elements. See [index()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index) in the API documentation for more information, particularly the examples.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var which_index = $("#tabs ul li a").index($("a[href='#All']"));
    alert(which_index);
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#CPU"><span>CPU</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Pickup"><span>Pickup</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Breakfix"><span>Breakfix</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#All"><span>All</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```