# Get each <li> index number with jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'm trying to get the index number of few `<li>`'s. The li's are 8 and I'm trying to get each li's number.

On each li click I do this function:

```
var str = $('#amastorage li').index();
alert(str);
```

Which always give's me 8.

**EDIT:**

This is how I get it:

```
$("#amastorage ul").find('a').click(function () {
        var str = $('#amastorage li').index();
        alert(str);
});
```

I cant change: `$("#amastorage ul").find('a').click(function () {` because It's from a plugin and it won't work.

Thanks

How can I alert the li number I choosed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Index Of Element Within UL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965825/get-index-of-element-within-ul)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `this` object in the click function.

http://jsfiddle.net/kuJWc/

```
$("li").click(function(){
    var str = $(this).index();
    alert(str);
});
```

per your edit:

```
$("#amastorage ul").find('a').click(function () {
        var str = $(this).parents("li").index();
        alert(str);
});
```

Comment: this is not the same as yours.  `$('#amastorage li').index();` will always give you 8 but  `$(this).index();` will not

Comment: @ jQuerybeast thats because its 0 based index (the first element is 0)

Comment: @Joseph Thank you. It works but I get everytime +1 value. So if I choose the second option I alert No3. I moved the default option at end but it works although that is not a go through. Is there a way to say $(this).parents("li").index(); minus 1?

Comment: @Joseph Forget it. I changed all the options value to +2 and it works. Thanks alot sir

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to loop through all the children of the ul and assign a click handler to each li like so:

```
$("#amastorage").children().each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var index = i;
        alert(index);
    });
});
```

Here's an example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/qAuUe/