# How to find index of list item (ul-li)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery object that is an HTML li element. How do I find what is the index of it in the context of its parent ul?

So if I have this:

```
<ul>
<li>abc</li>
<li id="test">def</li>
<li>hij</li>
</ul>
```

And this object:

```
$("test")
```

Is there a way to get the index number of this element. In this case it would be 1 (if you count 0 being the first index). Is there something I can do with $("test").parent()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get each <li> index number with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479229/get-each-li-index-number-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `$("#test").index()`. Note the use of the id selector `#`.

When [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is called without any parameters,

> the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first
>   element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

In this case this would be 1 -- [see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/zm9tc/).

Answer (score 0):

.index() is what you're looking for. Evaluates against its siblings, see the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/index/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index()`:

```
var index = $('#test').index();
```

Or, you can supply a selector, to get the index from a different set of matched elements:

```
var index = $('#test').index('li.className');
```

Which will get the index point for the `#test` element from among those elements with the `.className` (assuming that `#test` also had this class).

References:

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).