# get the index of a li element in a ul consisting of other html tags

Tags: jquery, html

Hi this below is my `ul` list.

```
<ul id="sortingCols">

 <li> <a href="#" class="floatright asc"><span>delete</span></a>
 <a href="#"    class="floatright desc"><span>delete</span></a>List item 1</li>

<li><a href="#" class="floatright asc"><span>delete</span></a>
<a href="#" class="floatright    desc"><span>delete</span></a>List item 1</li>

<li><a href="#" class="floatright asc"><span>delete</span></a>
<a href="#" class="floatright  desc"><span>delete</span></a>List item 1</li>

</ul>
```

I want to get the index of the `li` element among only the `li` elements
I tried this:

```
liIndex = jQuery('#sortingCols a').next().index();
```

But I am getting the index of the `li` elements among all the elements in the `ul` including the a tags.

How can I proceed?

Comment: You should not use any other tag directly inside a `ul` tag other than `li`. It would be valid to wrap your `a` tags inside `li` tags; but your mark-up at present is invalid.

Comment: *"How can I proceed?"* Fix your HTML, then http://stackoverflow.com/q/7479229/218196.

Comment: But i am able to render the layout as required using other tags inside the ul tag. If i use any other tag , even then how can i ge the index of an element among that particular elements only.

Comment: @user2523982: Since it's invalid HTML, I would not count on that. Some browser might still render it as you intend, others might not.

Comment: i am able to render it in safari. and my application is only for safari so i used it. is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: It doesn't matter, your HTML is broken, you should fix it.

Comment: i have edited the html now. On click of any a tag i need to get the the text associated with that particular li.

Answer (score 0):

onclick of ahref

```
$('a.desc').click(function(){
        liIndex = jQuery(this).index('#sortingCols a.desc');
        alert(liIndex);
    });

$('a.asc').click(function(){
        liIndex = jQuery(this).index('#sortingCols a.asc');
        alert(liIndex);
    });
```

update1

```
$('a').click(function(){
        liIndex = jQuery(this).parent().index('#sortingCols li');
        alert(liIndex);
    });
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37TRJ/1/)

Comment: i need to get the index of the li element associated with the a tag, on click of the a tag. on click of an a tag i need to get the index of the next li element basically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want this on click or some other event:

```
$('#sortingCols li').on('click', function() {
    var siblings = $(this).prevAll('li');

    console.log(siblings.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid, it should be:

```
<ul id="sortingCols">
  <li>
    List item 1
    <a href="#" class="floatright asc"><span>delete</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="floatright desc"><span>delete</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    List item 2
    <a href="#" class="floatright asc"><span>delete</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="floatright desc"><span>delete</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    List item 3
    <a href="#" class="floatright asc"><span>delete</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="floatright desc"><span>delete</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your JS code also needs to be (assuming you have other code working with this eg. .each():

```
liIndex = jQuery('#sortingCols li').index();
```

.next() will return the index of the next `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
liIndex = jQuery('#sortingCols a').find('li').index();
```

You can try second one also.

```
var allLIElements = jQuery('#sortingCols a').find('li');
liIndex = allLIElements.index(jQuery('#sortingCols a').next());
```